# Trying to grep/filter filename in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to filter filenames using grep. I have these filenames as input:

```
1234.txt
1234.txt.dev1
123.doc1
123.txt.dev1
123.txt.dev2
234.jpg
456.php
tmp
tmppppp
```

I want to list only those files which have one `.` (dot/period) in the filename. Filenames and extension will vary, they are not fixed.

Expected result:

```
1234.txt
123.doc1
234.jpg
456.php
```

Can I do this with grep?

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't particularly need `grep` for this at all. If you're processing names in a loop, you can check each of them easily enough: `if case $f in *.*.*) false;; *.*) true;; *) false;; esac; then echo "Name has exactly one period"; fi` works even in baseline POSIX sh -- no bash extensions, no grep extensions, etc.

Comment: Also note that it's unsafe to use a newline-delimited file for storing a list of filenames, as *newlines are valid in filenames*. If someone creates a file with `d=$'/tmp/ \n/etc/passwd\n' && mkdir -p -- "$d" && touch -- "$d/hi"`, you don't want code iterating over a list of filenames that includes that one to also modify/touch/read/interact with `/etc/passwd`. Use NUL-delimited lists, as created by `find -print0`, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) with per'ls regex switch :

```
grep -P '^[^.]+(?<!\.)[^.]+\.[^.]+$' file
```

[demo and explanations](https://regex101.com/r/7WKx94/2)

or simply (credit to @gniourf_gniourf) :

```
grep -E '^[^.]+\.[^.]+$' file
```

[demo and explanations](https://regex101.com/r/FN8vsW/1)

---

Another way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '{split($0, a, ".")} length(a) == 2' file
```

or

```
awk '!/^\./ && !/\.$/{split($0, a, ".")} length(a) == 2' file
```

if you want to skip files beginning or finishing with `.`

#### Output :

```
1234.txt
123.doc1
234.jpg
456.php
```

Comment: thanks. it gave expected result.
can you explain the syntax.

Comment: Have you checked the link ? There's all explanations on the right panel

Comment: Updated regex demo

Comment: Why not just `^[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$`?

Comment: Added awk way in my post and @gniourf_gniourf way

Comment: I'd suggest `[.]` as more reliable and consistent than `\.` (which can behave differently in contexts where the backslash is otherwise-consumed).